# Binding a byte[] to ImageView on Android using MvvmCross

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm trying to binding an ImageView to byte[].

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    local:MvxBind="Bitmap CaptchaImage, Converter=InMemoryImage"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
```

I'm using the tutorial from Picture Taking as a guide:
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/PictureTaking

But the image isn't showing.
What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: PS: I added the MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.PictureChooser from NuGet in my Android application and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file "PictureChooserPluginBootstrap.cs" was in my Bootstrap folder but somehow wasn't in my project.
All I needed was to "Include in Project" option.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of struggling with the xml you can just use this code in your java class:

```
public static void setImageViewWithByteArray(ImageView view, byte[] data) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

Please test it and tell me if it works.

Comment: This code is made in Java. Also the question is to bind it, and therefor you can't do something like this.